# Combine MVC Helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Is there anyway I can combine this MVC helper the only different is the `HtmlAttributes`.
I tried to do something like `@item.isRequired?HtmlAttributes`? but that didnt work.

```
 if (@item.isRequired)
 {
      @(Html.Kendo().RadioGroupFor(m => m.MeetingPollingQuestions)
      .Name(string.Format("PollingResponses[{0}].Value", idx))
      .HtmlAttributes(new { required = "required", data_val_required = "Question is 
      Required" })
        .Items(i=>
           {
              foreach (var option in @item.RadioButtonList)
                 i.Add().Label(option.Label).Value(option.Value);
              })
         .Value("Value")
       )
 }
 else
{
     @(Html.Kendo().RadioGroupFor(m => m.MeetingPollingQuestions)
     .Name(string.Format("PollingResponses[{0}].Value", idx))
     .Items(i=>
         {
         foreach (var option in @item.RadioButtonList)
             i.Add().Label(option.Label).Value(option.Value);
         })
      .Value("Value")
      )
}
```

Comment: You could define your own extension-method that wraps Kendo's `HtmlAttributes(...)` and adds a bool parameter and only calls `HtmlAttributes( required = "required", etc )` if that parameter is true.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: You don’t know how to write extension methods?

Comment: Do you mean a static class? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this would simply do the job

```
@{
  object reqAttributes = null;

    if(item.isRequired) {
        reqAttributes = new { required = "required" , data_val_required = "Question is 
  Required"  }
    }
    else {
        reqAttributes = new {  }
    }
}
```

An then

```
@(Html.Kendo().RadioGroupFor(m => m.MeetingPollingQuestions)
      .Name(string.Format("PollingResponses[{0}].Value", idx))
      .HtmlAttributes(reqAttributes )
        .Items(i=>
           {
              foreach (var option in @item.RadioButtonList)
                 i.Add().Label(option.Label).Value(option.Value);
              })
         .Value("Value")
       )
```